# openni kinect gazebo no depth data

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, openni-kinect, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to use the simulated kinect in gazebo, I just copy pasted the gazebo kinect snippet used in turtlebot and adapted it to my needs.
the topic /camera/image_raw is publishing and I can see the image in rviz
On the other hand no point cloud is being published on /camera/depth/points,
The topic has been started, just no data are published on it. Any ideas?
Regards, Moataz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10944/openni-kinect-gazebo-no-depth-data/) by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are on electric...

I am not sure about the missing image views in rviz, but w.r.t. the point clouds, you have just discovered a bug in the threshold logic based on connected clients in the gazebo_ros_camera plugin.  It's fixed in trunk.  One temporary hack around this bug is to:

1.
make sure no one is subscribed to the **image_raw** ros topic.
1.
now subscribe to the **points** topic

I'll shoot for a new release very soon.
sorry about the breakage.

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-19**:
I had originally fixed only gazebo_ros_camera, which would have not been enough...  just pushed same changes for gazebo_ros_openni_kinect in trunk.  Can someone else test it out and let me know it's working correctly before I make the final release?  Thanks.

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-08-18**:
when do you expect this fix to appear on unstable ubuntu repo?

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-08-18**:
are you talking about the snippet gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.cpp::updatechild(). if (!this->myParent->IsActive())
{
// do this first so there's chance for sensor to run 1 frame after activate
if (this->pointCloudConnectCount > 0)
{
this->myParent->SetActive(true);
this->myParent->SimulateDepthData(true);
}
else if (this->imageConnectCount > 0)
{
this->myParent->SimulateDepthData(false);
this->myParent->SetActive(true);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you running on electric or diamondback? The kinect plugin is only available in electric and not in diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-08-18**:
I´m running on unstable